# JDA getReaction().getEmoji().getAsReactionCode() not returning unicode emoji

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I'm trying to make a bot that when reacted to a message with some emojis it will post a slightly different message.

But seems that the method is not returning the unicode for those emojis, I placed a System.out.println but the only thing that seems to be returning is ? (alongside a unknown symbol according to debugger) anyone can help with it?

```
public class EmoteReactControler extends ListenerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReactionAdd(@NotNull MessageReactionAddEvent event){
        String reaction = event.getReaction().getEmoji().getAsReactionCode();
        User userReacted = event.getUser();
        Channel channel = event.getChannel();
        String channelMention = channel.getAsMention();
        String jumpLink = event.getJumpUrl();
        String answer = "nothing";
        System.out.println(reaction);
        if ( reaction.equals("U+1F600")) {
            answer = "one";
        } else if (reaction.equals("U+1F601")) {
            answer = "two";
        } else if (reaction.equals("U+1F60D")) {
            answer = "three";
        } else if (reaction.equals("U+1F62D")){
            answer = "four";
        }

        String message = userReacted.getName() + " did " + answer + " see here: " + jumpLink + " in " + channelMention;
        event.getGuild().getTextChannelById(channel.getId()).sendMessage(message).queue();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from the code you provided, it looks like you are trying to get the reaction in codepoint notation. You can [`ReactionEmote#getAsCodepoints`](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/MessageReaction.ReactionEmote.html#getAsCodepoints()) do do this. Example:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReactionAdd(@NotNull MessageReactionAddEvent event){
    String codepoints = event.getReactionEmote().getAsCodepoints();
    String answer;

    switch(codepoints) {
        case "U+1F600":
            answer = "one";
            break;
        case "U+1F601": 
            answer = "two";
            break;
        case "U+1F60D":
            answer = "three";
            break;
        case "U+1F62D":
            answer = "four";
            break;
        default:
            answer = "nothing"
            break;
    }    

    // ...
}
```

Keep in mind that `getAsCodepoints` can throw an IllegalStateException if the reaction is not a valid UTF-8 character (e.i. a custom server emote). You may want to use escaped unicode characters instead of codepoints and stick with [`ReactionEmote#getAsReactionCode`](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/MessageReaction.ReactionEmote.html#getAsReactionCode()), as this does not throw any exceptions and would seem to work best in this context. Example:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReactionAdd(@NotNull MessageReactionAddEvent event){
    String reaction = event.getReaction().getEmoji().getAsReactionCode();
    String answer;
    
    switch(codepoints) {
        case "\uD83D\uDE00":
            answer = "one";
            break;
        case "\uD83D\uDE01": 
            answer = "two";
            break;
        case "\uD83D\uDE0D":
            answer = "three";
            break;
        case "\uD83D\uDE2D":
            answer = "four";
            break;
        default:
            answer = "nothing"
            break;
    }    

    // ...
}
```

I like to use the website [fileformat.info](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/) when dealing with Java and unicode because it has an **Encodings** table which lists a `C/C++/Java source code` column.

### Note on `?`

---

If you are using a terminal that is not configured to use UTF-8 (such as out-of-the-box Eclipse), then unicode characters will be displayed as `?`.

You can configure the Eclipse console to use UTF-8 encoding by going to **Run** > **Run Configurations**, selecting the configuration for your. application, then going to the **Common** tab and setting **Encoding** to UTF-8:

[image: run configurations]